# Multiple RDS Sync with Auto Scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds

I would like to allow for scaling of our RDS databases for an application but can't seem to find any information on how to keep multiple RDS databases in sync with the same data. Any ideas how to set up such a configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only scale with read replicas. RDS does not support multi-master.

Comment: any ideas on the best way to set up read replicas? or if i do want to set up a multi master, how could i go about doing that?

Comment: By scale, he definitely means vertical Storage Scaling and not scaling out instances.